# Multiple menu locations in taxonomy menu

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've used [taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) version 7.x-1.5. Due to this module I can only added taxonomy menus into single menu location.

But I want to add a taxonomy menu into multiple menus. Is it possible? If yes, how to do this?

I've attached image. Please look it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add menu items that link to the taxonomy terms as many times as you want - but that Taxonomy Menu option will only manage a single one.

You could potentially write a custom module that automatically inserts the same item into other menus at the same time - but that might be more complicated than you want.